# find closest span by its class into a tr

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi I've done many search everywhere in google and in that website but I definitely have problem with my selector.

Hi have a dynamic table generated by php. I have some buttons to edit content, So I try to edit it while clicking on edit button but it does not seems to find the good item. In fact in finds nothing.

Acutaly I have :

a button for each row called edit it has a class called `changer_etat`

Then I have the jquery code :

```
$('.changer_etat').click(function(){
   var date_depart = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.date_depart').val();
   console.log(date_depart);
});
```

I try to find a `span` called `date_etat` in the current `tr` where is the button I clicked in.

But actualyit returns to me nothing, I've tried many things, and done some searches but with no success.

I've tried this

`$('.changer_etat').click(function(){
       var date_depart = $(this).closest('span.date_depart').val();
       console.log(date_depart);
    });`

that returns undefined

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use need [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) not [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
$('.changer_etat').click(function(){
   var date_depart = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.date_depart').text();
   console.log(date_depart);
});
```

Comment: thanks it works great. You a genius, I started Jquery since 1 week and it is not often easy... I thought .val was to find every value. thanks a lot

Comment: @user2506760 `.val()` works with form elements like `input,textarea,select etc`.Welcome Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use a dynamic selector since your table is being generated dynamically. Also, as others have noted you will want to use `html` because you're grabbing the *html* of the span. Spans don't have a value attribute.

```
$('html').on('click', '.changer_etat', function(){
   var date_depart = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.date_depart').html();
   console.log(date_depart);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `html()`

```
$('.changer_etat').click(function(){
   var date_depart = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.date_depart').html();
console.log(date_depart);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a typo between "find('span.date_depart')" and "find a span called date_etat"? At least this works on Firefox 25.0 / Linux:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.changer_etat').click(function() {
                var date_depart = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.date_etat').html();
                console.log("date_depart="+date_depart);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td><span class="date_etat">i am content 1</span></td><td><button class="changer_etat">button action</button></td></tr>
            <tr><td><span class="date_etat">i am content 2</span><button class="changer_etat">button action</button></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```